# NSWindow move CGRect

Tags: cocoa

what do i have to do, to get the LIVE-Change of the CGRect during movement of the NSWindow. (not before and not after, just LIVE-movement). Do I have to overwrite setFrame method?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe you'd need to override `-setFrame:`.